# Connecting Team Explorer to Codeplex anonymously

Tags: version-control, tfs, codeplex

I was using Codeplex and tried connecting to their source control using Team Explorer, with no joy.

I also tried connecting with HTTPS or HTTP, using the server name and the project name. As I do not have a user account on Codeplex I could not login.

I am just trying to check out some code without changing it. My question is:

How can I connect Team Explorer to a Codeplex server anonymously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to use the [CodePlex Source Control Client](http://www.codeplex.com/CodePlexClient). In includes cpc.exe which supports the anonymous access features of CodePlex TFS servers for non-coordinator/developer access. But according to the site:

> The CodePlex Client is not currently
>   being maintained. The focus of the
>   CodePlex team now is on the [SvnBridge](http://www.codeplex.com/SvnBridge).

I'm using TortoiseSVN with SvnBridge with no problems.

Answer (score 3):

As the person primarily responsible for making anonymous access work against the TFS CodePlex servers, I can tell you that it isn't possible with Team Explorer. We tried to make it happen, but the way you get anonymous to work would've caused a pretty stellar-sized security hole with Team Explorer.

So, as others have mentioned, the custom-written clients (CPC and SvnBridge) do support anonymous. I know the Teamprise guys were talking about adding it to Teamprise for a while, but not sure if they ever got around to it. It would've been a pretty big change in the way they work (since it basically has to be Workspace-less).

**Edit:** Brannon helped, too. Wrote all the horrible C++ that I refuse to write. He just bugged me on IM, so I better amend my previous remarks. :-p

Comment: I also spiked the original SvnBridge implementation, but I don't think any of that code survived :)

Comment: P.S. C++ is horrible. Did I mention that? Not like, "write songs and be a moderately successful villain who can't get the girl" horrible, because that's fun, but the "walking on glass in your bare feet" horrible.

Comment: We have the anonymous support still on our back-log at Teamprise, but like you say it is a fairly big deal for us because we work in a very similar way to the Visual Studio client - i.e. most version control operations are performed off the Workspace object in the Version Control API.  I still hope we'll get to it one day, but sadly it will not be soon.

Answer (score 2):

I have used [SVNBridge](http://www.codeplex.com/SvnBridge) with TortoiseSVN, which workes like a charm.

What I was looking for here is a way for anonymous access that is directly integrated with VS. Guess that's not possible at the moment.

Also just found out [you can connect directly](http://stevenharman.net/blog/archive/2008/09/09/subversion-support-on-codeplex.aspx) via TortoiseSVN, without SVNBridge. Look for the "SvnBridge on the CodePlex servers?" heading

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible with Team Explorer. But you can with [CodePlex Source Control Client](http://www.codeplex.com/CodePlexClient) or [Tortoise](http://www.codeplex.com/CodePlex/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Using%20TortoiseSVN%20with%20CodePlex&referringTitle=Source%20control%20clients)